# how to read specially formatted coordinates from a text file to calculate distance between them?

Tags: c++, string, file, format, maps

My initial program was designed to take the type of the geometric object from the user then takes the coordinates of each line to calculate the area of the shape. It had one problem which is whenever I asked the user to enter the two coordinates that make a line, the second coordinate would be repeated again as the first for the next line.

example: 
the first line he would enter 0 0 0 1 (stands for x1 y1 x2 y2)
the second line the input would be 0 1 1 0 (x2 y2 x3 y3)

you can see that 0 1 were repeated again which was not a problem in the first stage of the program.

The second stage when I tried to upgrade my program, I started taking input from files formatted like this:  rectangle,(42,25),(68,25),(68,70),(42,70)

I can read each coordinate alone using

```
fscanf(file, "(%lf,%lf)", &X, &Y);
```

but how can I take the second coordinate again and repeat it for the next input like I explained in the above example.

methods of the old class

```
Point::Point(double x, double y)
{
    X = x;
    Y = y;
} 

Point::Point()
{
    cout << "Point constructor called! enter the x and y co-ordinates" << endl;
    cin >> X >> Y;


    //this is what I want to modify 
}

double operator-(const Point& Start, const Point& End)
{
    // returns the distance between two points

    return sqrt(pow((End.X - Start.X), 2.0) + pow((End.Y - Start.Y), 2.0));
}
```

Comment: BTW, you may want to consider using `x * x` rather than `pow(x, 2)`.  Usually the multiplication is faster because it avoids function call and return overhead.

Comment: I recommend not having I/O in the constructor.  You can create methods for reading in different formats and you may want to consider overloading `operator>>`.

Comment: See also *initialization lists*, such as `Point(double x, double y) : X(x), Y(y) {}`.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thank you, but can you suggest a solution for this problem?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews my program can calculate the area when given each coordinate twice, How can I avoid this I really can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you should overload `operator>>` to read in a coordinate:

```
struct Coordinate
{
  double x;
  double y;
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Coordinate& co);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Coordinate& co)
{
    char c;
    input >> c; '('
    input >> co.x;
    input >> c; ','
    input >> co.y;
    input >> c; ')'
    return input;
}
```

Next, you can read in coordinates into a container:

```
std::vector<Coordinate> points;
Coordinate p;
while (input_file >> p)
{
    points.push_back(p);
    char c;
    input_file >> c;
}
```

You could augment your Coordinate structure by adding other methods:

```
struct Coordinate
{
    //...
    // Calculate y1 - this
    double absolute_distance(const Coordinate& y1) const;
};

double
Coordinate ::
absolute_distance(const Coordinate& y1) const
{
  const double x_diff(y1.x - x);
  const double y_diff(y1.y - y);
  const double x_diff_squared(x_diff * x_diff);
  const double y_diff_squared(y_diff * y_diff);
  return abs(sqrt(x_diff_squared + y_diff_squared));
}
```

This would allow you to calculate the distance between two coordinates:

```
double distance = points[1].absolute_distance(points[0]);
```

Following this technique, you should be able to calculate the area with 4 coordinates.